# Android menu using slide menu library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, nullpointerexception, slidingmenu

I am using sliding menu library in my project it was working nice, but I uninstalled my app from the device and installed it again through Eclipse. The size of the app was reduced from 7.92 MB to 6.92 MB.
And where the sliding menu should appear in an Activity, it is not opening and the following errors are in my logcat.

### Logcat

```
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049): Process: com.example.sayminicabdriver, PID:   4049
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start                   activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sayminicabdriver/mapslider.sliding}:              java.lang.NullPointerException
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3353)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.setContent(CustomViewAbove.java:436)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.setContent(SlidingMenu.java:356)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.attachToActivity(SlidingMenu.java:332)     
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu.attachToActivity(SlidingMenu.java:292)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at mapslider.sliding.onCreate(sliding.java:122)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
        11-17 17:58:52.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4049):     ... 11 more
```

My code was running well for me before, but suddenly this error came.

### java code

```
                      @Override
                      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                      setBehindContentView(R.layout.content_frame);
                      SlidingMenu menu_bus = new SlidingMenu(this);
                      SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
                      sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
                      sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
                      sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
                      sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
                      sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

                      menu_bus.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
//firs slide menu, then second
                     getSlidingMenu().setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
                  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new                       MenuFragment()).commit();

        getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(50);                  
     //   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
      //  getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);        

        getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.right_main);
        getSlidingMenu().setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
//start fragment for second menu
getSupportFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.right_container, new RightFragment(),"test_bus")
.commit();

         Button csButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


        csButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getSlidingMenu().showMenu();

    }//inside csButton1 onclick listener just need to call 

});
   // inside csButton onclick listener just need to call slidingMenu.showSecondaryMenu();
     Button csButton1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
   csButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        getSlidingMenu().showSecondaryMenu();

    }
}) ;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's on `sliding.java` line `142`

Comment: it's right menu button

Comment: csButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  
    
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getSlidingMenu().showMenu();
    
   }//inside csButton1 onclick listener just need to call 
   
  });

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the project and make sure the library is used (right click project, properties) or in java built path

Comment: hmm maybe you forget the purpose using two SlidingMenu(menu_bus & sm) just analyze again the code and match it with the tutorial in here 
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/blob/master/example/src/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/example/LeftAndRightActivity.java

Comment: my app was working well with this code and this code is same to the tutorial. but after re installing this error is coming